# iOS:How to make statusBar position animate?

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationbar

I recently get a demand,which is make `navigation bar` move up to dismiss, that is let `navigation bar` do position animation.
Somebody know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have token a method to animate my `navigation bar` like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y-NAVIGATIONBARHEIGHT, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);}
                     completion:^(BOOL completion){

                     }];
```